# Numpy error with python 2.7.12

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, importerror

I have both python2.7 and python3.5 installed on Ubuntu 16.04. After I write import numpy in python2.7 environment, I get the following error,

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: cannot import name multiarray
```

But with python3 I am facing no such trouble with numpy. Please suggest a solution if anyone has faced similar issue.

Comment: Why does your Python 2.7.12 interpreter try to import Python 3.5's `numpy`?

Comment: I am being unable to figure out the same, could you please tell me how to change that..

Answer (score 0):

you are importing a version of Numpy who are for python 3.5

you must download the version who are  for 2.7
you can find the download packages of numpy as : http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Comment: Those packages are for Windows, not Ubuntu.